# How do I use another value of a key in a hash if the first one doesn't exist, like some type of fallback in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Basically I have a follow button and when click the page refreshes and I show an unfollow button in place. Below is the code I use to render the particular form needed:

**follow_forms partial:**

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'relationships/partials/unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'relationships/partials/follow' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any I changed the form to an ajax form because I don't want the page refresh and on success of the form submission I'd like to replace the follow button/form with an unfollow button/form. This isn't straight forward because only 1 form shows at a time so I can't use my jquery selector to find this form anyway.

What I decided to do was create a new action that renders the follow_form partial this way the appropriate form will be available for me to manipulate with my jquery selector.

**The new action:**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def get_follow_form
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :partial => 'relationships/partials/follow_form_ajax' }
    end
  end
end
```

The problem now is that I don't have access to the @user instance variable. That doesn't matter to much because I can get the user who was just followed via the jquery success data then pass that as data in the new ajax call to get_follow_form_url and then pass that info into the partial as a local variable.

I still have an issue with the @user instance variable not being available. Which brings me to my question.

How can I make another value be used if the instance variable isn't nil/doesn't exist?

**The form for following:**

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @user.id), :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
<%= f.submit "Follow", :class => 'followButton' %>
<% end %>
```

Can I do something like this

```
 :followed_id => @user.id <-if this doesn't exist use this-> user.id
```

There are other ways around this like creating new partials that are only used for this whole situation or creating some messy if statements but I feel like creating duplicate forms should be my very very very last option.

I look forward to you solutions thanks

Kind regards

Comment: If you know who the user is why not set @user?

Comment: This was the solution. Wasn't studying my code hard enough. This was staring me right in the face. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple way to do this, assuming you have your 'fallback' ID:

```
:followed_id => @user.present? ? @user.id : fallback_id
```

Comment: Wasn't the solution but it was the answer to my question thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the [andand gem](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) or just `try` and a logic expression:

```
:followed_id => @user.andand.id || user.id
```

Even without that you can use identical logic, and certainly don't need multiple partials:

```
:followed_id => (@user && @user.id) || user.id
```

But as Frederick says, if you have a replacement value for the object already, couldn't you just set it?

Comment: Yea, I set the instance variable. Fredericks suggestion was the solution.